# SharePoint Federated Results, how to restrict Bing Searching to a specific URL?

Tags: search-results, federated-search

Let's say I'm using Bing for federated results in SharePoint 2010.  Is there any way I can restrict the results to a particular URL in the configuration for everyone? Say I only want the results from http://www.yahoo.com and everything underneath to show up in Bing only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bing supports site scoping in much the same way as google.  Simply add `" site:yahoo.com"` to your search query (url-encoded of course) and it will only return results from that domain.